# How to position tooltip wherever mouse entered div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-bootstrap

I have played with this for a while now and could not figure it out by myself. What I am trying to achieve, is to place a tooltip on the top of the div, however, not in the middle - but in the position, where the user entered his mouse into the div.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Any code to show? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple tooltip

HTML :

```
<div data-tooltip="This is my tooltip">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div:hover:before {
content: attr(data-tooltip);
position: absolute;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: -3px 0 0 180px;
background: black;
color: white;
border-radius: 3px;
}

div:hover:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
margin: 6px 0 0 3px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid black;
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: 125px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```